# Vue js dynamic data component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm passing some dynamic data from a parent component to a child component using **props** ..   So I would like to know how I can add *myColor* prop to *total* value and show it an render the result in a final value.
I've already update the post with the parent component (shapes) and the child component (colors)

I'm using Vue 2 and webpack.

```
//parent component

<v-layout row wrap primary-title v-for="shape in shapes" :key="shape.id">
        <v-layout column>
            <v-flex >
                <v-subheader>{{shape.name}} {{shape.price}}€ {{selectedShape.price}}</v-subheader>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-layout>
        <my-colors :myShape="selectedShape.price"></my-colors>

<script>

import Colors from './Colors.vue';

export default {

    components: {
        Colors
    },

    data() {

        return {
            selectedShape: {},
            shapes: [{
                id: 1,
                name: "Square",
                price: 4,
                href: "../../static/square.jpg"
            }, {
                id: 2,
                name: "Circle",
                price: 6,
                href: "../../static/circle.jpg"
            }]
        }
    },

    computed: {

        totalShape: function() {
            var totalShape = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
                if (this.shapes[i].selected) {
                    totalShape += this.shapes[i].price;
                }
            }
            return totalShape;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getSelectedShape() {
                return this.selectedShape;

            },
    }
}

</script>


//child component
     <v-layout>
                <v-layout>
                    <v-flex >
                        <h3 >Total price:</h3>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
                <v-layout>
                    <v-flex 
                        <v-subheader> {{total}} {{myShape}}   €</v-subheader>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-layout>

        <script>

          export default {
              props: ['myShape'],

              data: () => ({

                  checked1: '',
                  showCart: false,
                  colors: [{
                      id: 1,
                      name: "white",
                      price: 2,
                      checked: '',
                  }, {
                      id: 2,
                      name: "black",
                      price: 2.0,
                      checked: '',
                  }, {
                      id: 3,
                      name: "Grey",
                      price: 2.25,
                      checked: '',
                  }, {
                      id: 4,
                      name: "Blue",
                      price: 1.6,
                      checked: '',
                  }, {
                      id: 5,
                      name: "Red",
                      price: 2.5,
                      checked: '',
                  }, {
                      id: 6,
                      name: "Yellow",
                      price: 2.75,
                      checked: '',
                  }],
              }),

              computed: {

                  total: function() {
                      var total = 0;
                      for (var i = 0; i < this.colors.length; i++) {
                          if (this.colors[i].checked) {
                              total += this.colors[i].price;
                          }
                      }
                      return total; 
                  },
              },
          }

          </script>
```

Comment: if you post more code I think it would help.

Comment: @82Tuskers already updated. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand your needs from this script, but be aware of one way data flow in Vue. So, you can send data from parent component to child component in which its will be accessible through props, but not from child component to parent. Use Vuex if you need two-way data flow between components.

```js
var child = {
  template: '#child',
  props: ['fromParent']
}

Vue.component('parent', {
  template: '#parent',
  components: {
    child: child
  },
  props: ['fromInstance']
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    instanceData: {
      text: 'Original value'
    }
  },
  created () {
    var self = this
    setTimeout(_ => self.instanceData.text = 'Changed value', 3000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent :from-instance="this.instanceData"></parent>
</div>

<template id="parent">
  <div>
    <child :from-parent="this.fromInstance"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="child">
  <p>{{this.fromParent.text}}</p>
</template>
```

Example with SELECT:

```js
var child = {
  template: '#child',
  props: ['selected']
}

Vue.component('parent', {
  template: '#parent',
  components: {
    child: child
  },
  props: ['options'],
  data () {
    return {
      parentCar: 'none'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update (e) {
      this.parentCar = e.target.value
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: {
      audi: 'Audi',
      bmw: 'BMW',
      mercedes: 'Mercedes',
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent :options="this.items"></parent>
</div>

<template id="parent">
  <div>
    <select @change="update">
      <option value="none" selected>Car</option>
      <option v-for="(value, key) in options" :value="key">
        {{ value }}
      </option>
    </select>
    <child :selected="this.parentCar"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="child">
  <p>{{ selected }}</p>
</template>
```

Example with checked / unchecked checkbox:

```js
var child = {
  template: '#child',
  props: ['checked']
}

Vue.component('parent', {
  template: '#parent',
  components: {
    child: child
  },
  data () {
    return {
      checkbox: false
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <parent></parent>
</div>

<template id="parent">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkbox">
    <child :checked="this.checkbox"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="child">
  <p>{{ checked }}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying just to send some dynamic data from the parent component to the child, and being rendered on the child component.

Comment: Wait, Im adding example

Comment: Just simple example demontrating how to send data from instance to component and then to child component.

Comment: A comment regarding the one-way-flow in Vue. If you pass an object as a prop, and the child changes the object properties, the parent will see the changes as well (objects are passed by reference). It might not be best practice to achieve two-way data-flow this way, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Looks really cool. But the thing It's how I could add a selected value from the parent component and be rendered on the child  component as a dynamic value. So each time I select/deselect an option on the parent component it will updates on the child component

Comment: Added example with SELECT :) But. select element, not select / deselect :) My bad, Im working on select/deselect :)